# Matching the controls of Mortal Kombat X with my Logitech F310

Tags: controllers, mortal-kombat-x

My friend recently purchased Mortal Kombat X. I have Mortal Kombat 9 on steam (from some sale I'm sure) which I've never played, but I want to start practicing for when we hang out.

I stayed up until 2am last night playing... I started out having my butt handed to me by the lowest level AI, spent a few hours practicing moves in training, and then managed to memorize a few combos and special moves, before finally beating my first opponent.

However, my friend has Mortal Kombat X on the PS4. I would like to configure my gamepad so that the buttons work the same as the dualshock controller, so I don't have to relearn all the combos. One time I played SSB on a custom controller and the buttons were all out of order and since I was relying on muscle memory... I got my butt kicked. That's what I want to avoid :)

Here's the default configuration:

[image]

**What's the default configuration for MKX on a dualshock controller?** I couldn't find any resources online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's control layout straight from the game. Preset 1 is the default.
[image]

And here's controller buttons just for good measure:
[image]